# JavaScript - Trying to move an image upon keyboard press

Tags: javascript

I am just learning ***JavaScript*** coding and trying to move an image from left to right upon a keyboard press but unable to figure out the same.

I have defined the image individually in `Father.js` file and in the `sketch.js` file - I am trying to write the code to move the image.

Can anyone help please?

Here's the link to the code - https://github.com/Salma-Siddiqua/Self-game-stage-2

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add "eventListeners" for keyboard press either "up" or "down" or "press" I guess. And then inside the "eventListener" you can specify your image movement

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `Matter` or whatever engine you're using here, but when you want to move something based on user input - and in a game loop - you should move it based on some rate × the deltaTime between each draw. By that I mean: if a character should move at 30 pixels per second when the right-arrow key is pressed, you need to figure out how much time has elapsed since your last draw, then determine which direction to move things in and by how much. Your x,y transformation is a factor of how much time has passed.

So - with each draw you need to store some kind of timestamp / millisecond count.

In terms of capturing user input in the browser, you can do it with events. ie:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   /*
      left = 37
      up = 38
      right = 39
      down = 40
   */
   if (e.which == 37) doSomething();
});
```

There are other events you could use. 'keyup' etc.